# BASH: Сохранить столбцы в отдельные переменные

Tags: bash, unix

Некая команда (пусть будет foobar) выводит таблицу с данными, например такую:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    aaa  eee  hhh
2    bbb  fff  iii
3    ccc  ggg  jjj
```

Нужно. Как-то выбрать из этой таблицы значения столбцов 1 и 3 и записать в переменные var1 и var2 соответственно. То есть на выходе должно получиться var1="1 2 3", var2="eee fff ggg". Причем команду foobar можно запустить только 1 раз (она долго выполняется и запускать ее на каждый столбец получится очень не производительно). Желательно в одну строку, желательно через awk. Суть в том что эти данные в дальнейшем должны использоваться в цикле нужны в удобном виде данные из этих 2 столбцов и так чтобы не запускать foobar больше 1 раза.

Answer (score 1):

скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read c1 c2 c3 garbage; do 
  v1+=" $c1"; v2+=" $c3"; 
done <<< "$(foobar | sed '1d')"

# обрезаем первый символ (пробел)
v1=${v1:1}
v2=${v2:1}

# проверочный вывод на предмет затесавшихся лишних пробелов
echo "'$v1'"
echo "'$v2'"
```

на приведённых данных он возвращает:

```
'1 2 3'
'eee fff ggg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Как присвоить вывод двум разным переменным для вашего случая не знаю, но вывод нужных вам столбцов с помощью awk можно сделать так:

```
$ foobar | awk 'NR == 2 {c1=$1; c3=$3}; NR > 2 { c1=c1" "$1; c3=c3" "$3 }; END { print c1; print c3 }'
```

Если не принципиальны пробелы в качестве разделителей, то присвоить значения переменным можно так:

```
$ read c1 c3 << EOF
$ $(foobar| awk 'NR == 2 {c1=$1; c3=$3}; NR > 2 { c1=c1";"$1; c3=c3";"$3 }; END { print c1, c3 }')
$ EOF
```

В результате для вашего примера получится следующее:

```
$ echo $c1
1;2;3
$ echo $c3
eee;fff;ggg
```