# Не получается добавить элемент к массиву

Tags: linux, bash

Существует файл `/tmp/test` с содержимым

```
2018-05-12 17:00 28170706 12-May-2018-17-00-02.gz
2018-05-12 18:00 28168202 12-May-2018-18-00-02.gz
2018-05-12 19:00 28165338 12-May-2018-19-00-01.gz
```

и скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=()

cat /tmp/test | while read -r i; do
if [[ `echo $i|awk {'print $1'}` =~ [[:alpha:]] ]]
then
    continue
fi
if [[ $i != "" ]]; then
FILE=`echo $i|awk {'print $4'}`
FILES+=("$FILE")
fi                                                                                         
done                                                                                                         
echo "${FILES[@]}"
```

смысл которого просто сформировать массив с содержимым `12-May-2018-17-00-02.gz 12-May-2018-18-00-02.gz 12-May-2018-19-00-01.gz` и т.д. , но почему-то массив у меня пустой всегда :( Я уже 2 часа на этот дурацкий массив убил. подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `readarray FILES  <  /tmp/test`. Это всё.

Comment: @0xdb агонь! Только надо именно в цикле, потому что это лишь упрощённый кусок скрипта который не работает. В действительности там в цикле перед внесением в массив ещё 100500 дел делается :(

Comment: как минимум: `$i` → `"$i"`. везде.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в смысле это в скрипте надо везде поменять? Пробовал, и сейчас снова сделал - всё так же `echo "${FILES[@]}"` возвращает пустую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. при использовании «трубы» (aka «конвейер», aka `|`) создаются как минимум два новых процесса:

   ```
   новый-процесс | новый-процесс
   ```

   каждый новый процесс может поменять только **свои** локальные переменные, и не окажет никакого влияния на переменные родительского процесса.

   имеет смысл убрать «трубу». т.е., вместо:

   ```
   cat файл | while read ... done
   ```

   использовать перенаправление:

   ```
   while read ... done < файл
   ```
2. можно значительно упростить то, что внутри цикла, сразу получая нужные куски строк в локальные переменные:

   ```
   while read f1 f2 f3 f4 other; do
     if [ "$f1" ... ]; then ... fi
     if [ "$f4" ... ]; then ... fi
   ```
3. если данные в цикл поступают не из файла, а из другой команды, то можно написать, например, так:

   ```
   while read ...; do ... done < <(другая команда)
   ```

---

ну и побольше кавечек вокруг тех переменных, которые получают какие-то динамические значения из «внешнего мира». кавычками переменную не испортишь!

```
if [ $i ... ]   # очень плохо!
if [ "$i" ... ] # очень хорошо
```

---

связанные вопросы:

- [BASH: Сохранить столбцы в отдельные переменные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/462067/178576)
- [Как отсортировать двумерный/ассоциативный массив на bash?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617751/178576)

Comment: Агонь! Только не работает. Может у меня с `bash` что-то не так? `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: отлично работает: `$ f=(); while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 garbage; do f+=("$f4"); done < test; echo ${f[@]}`

Comment: ok, допустим. А почему не работает пример что привёл я? Ну либо фиг с ним, подскажите тогда как вместо `done < файл` сделать `done < команда_возвращающая_вот_тот_список` чтоб не получать `ambiguous redirect`?

Comment: @user297162, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да, сапсибо, я уже нашёл: `... done <<< "$(/bin/my_other_command with some args)"` . Сейчас у меня другая проблема - как из этого массива удалять элементы с конца, до тех пор пока их не останется определённое кол-во, ну, например, 4. Но это наверно сложно и надо другой вопрос создать если не найду сам :(

Comment: Кавычками запросто можно испортить переменную. Ну не умеет народ готовить shell, как ни крути. Очень сложный язык программирования.